# How to use random name for image file generated using ffmpeg-php?

Tags: php, image, ffmpeg

The image is generating fine with the below code

```
$thumbnail = 'images/thumbnail.jpg';

// shell command [highly simplified, please don't run it plain on your script!]

shell_exec("ffmpeg -i $video -deinterlace -an -ss 1 -t 00:00:01 -r 1 -y -vcodec mjpeg -f mjpeg $thumbnail 2>&1");
```

But it creates a file named `thumbnail.jpg`
I need to have random name for images generated to save it in the images folder and database. How can i generate a random name to thumbnail in the below code
`$thumbnail = 'images/thumbnail.jpg';`

Comment: What are the requirements for this "random name"?  If you mean you want something like thumbnail1.jpg then you could easily query the row count of the table you are storing the jpg's in and add one to that and append it to the end of the file name.

Comment: @MichaelPlatt I need to add the current time , random number , and which should looks like.              this , $thumbnail = 'images/thumbnail+currentTime+randomnumber.jpg' .. I am a total beginner.. so please do help

Comment: So how about you make another variable, call it something like `$thumbnail_output` and set the value to be `thumbnail`.  Create another variable called date like so `$date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());` and stick the the two together as the output file name?

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$rand = rand(1,10000);
$uniqueName = uniqid($rand);
$thumbnail = "images/{$uniqueName}.jpg";
```

It will create a unique name for the thumbnail image. Using [`uniqid()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) and [`rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php)

Comment: @rak007 And as the answer says, it is not random enough to be used for security tokens. But it is not the case here. As the OP only wants to use the random string as filename, which it can do pretty well, especially when being provided a `prefix`

Comment: @mega6382 Thanks for the answer , helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

change the line

```
$thumbnail = 'images/thumbnail.jpg';
```

to

```
$thumbnail = 'images/img'.rand(99,999999).'.jpg';
```

it will create a random name for the image.

Comment: what if I want to save 1000000 images ?

Comment: Change rand(99,999999) to rand(99,999999999). :)

Comment: On 1 million images, still have a huge chance to encounter the same rand number twice ...

Comment: $thumbnail = 'images/img'.time().rand(99,99999).'.jpg'; Time function will solve the issue. There is no chanse to upload more than 1 million images in 1 particular second.

Comment: there's always "that guy" and this is you haha

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: @NithinJohn Your solution, is incorrect, because the `rand()` will output same number multiple times which will create conflicts.

Comment: @mega6382  Its a rare possibility in 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

Random will never grant that EVERY filename generated this way is unique and not already in use.

I suggest using [tempnam](http://php.net/manual/en/function.tempnam.php)

Here is an example :

```
$tmpfname = tempnam("/YOURDIR", "images");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Since you stated in your comment that you need your filename to look like

```
$thumbnail = 'images/thumbnail+currentTime+randomnumber.jpg'
```

here's the code to do just that:

```
$thumbnail = 'images/thumbnail' . time() . rand(1,9) . '.jpg';
```

I suggest you edit your post and paste these requirements so other users can easily find them.